# How to retrieve the min and max times of a timestamp column based on a time interval of 30 mins?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, data-science, data-analysis

I am trying to pull a desired output that looks like this

```
   Driver_ID|   Interval_Start_Time     |  Interval_End_Time      |    Clocked_In_Time      |   Clocked_Out_Time      |  Score
    232     |  2019-04-02 00:00:00.000  | 2019-04-02 00:30:00.000 | 2019-04-02 00:10:00.000 | 2019-04-02 00:29:00.000 |  0.55
```

My Goal is to pull the ID in 30 minute or per half hour time intervals, and their min or earliest clocked in time and max or latest clocked out time in that same 30 minute or half hour interval.

The query I have currently is

```
WITH TIME AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT CASE
                       WHEN extract(MINUTE
                                    FROM offer_time_utc)<30 THEN date_trunc('hour', offer_time_utc)
                       ELSE date_add('minute',30, date_trunc('hour', offer_time_utc))
                   END AS interval_start_time,
                   CASE
                       WHEN extract(MINUTE
                                    FROM offer_time_utc)<30 THEN date_add('minute',30, date_trunc('hour', offer_time_utc))
                       ELSE date_add('hour',1, date_trunc('hour', offer_time_utc))
                   END AS interval_end_time
   FROM integrated_delivery.trip_offer_fact offer
   WHERE offer.business_day = date '2019-04-01' )
SELECT DISTINCT offer.Driver_ID,
                offer.region_uuid,
                interval_start_time,
                interval_end_time,
                min(sched.clocked_in_time_utc) AS clocked_in_time,
                max(sched.clocked_out_time_utc) AS clocked_out_time,
                cast(scores.acceptance_rate AS decimal(5,3)) AS acceptance_rate
FROM integrated_delivery.trip_offer_fact offer
JOIN TIME ON offer.offer_time_utc BETWEEN time.interval_start_time AND time.interval_end_time
JOIN integrated_delivery.courier_actual_hours_fact sched ON offer.Driver_ID = sched.Driver_ID
JOIN integrated_product.driver_score_v2 scores ON offer.Driver_ID = scores.courier_id
AND offer.region_uuid = scores.region_id
AND offer.region_uuid = sched.region_uuid
AND offer.business_day = date '2019-04-01'
AND sched.business_day = date '2019-04-01'
AND scores.extract_dt = 20190331
AND offer.region_uuid IN('930c534f-a6b6-4bc1-b26e-de5de8930cf9')
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,7
```

But it does not seem to give me the correct min and max clocked in and clocked out time in that correct interval as below,

```
    driver_uuid  region_uuid   interval_start_time      interval_end_time           clocked_in_time         clocked_out_time      score 
      232              bbv     2019-04-01 14:30:00.000   2019-04-01 15:00:00.000  2019-04-01 14:43:13.140  2019-04-01 22:30:46.043   0.173
```

When I add in these 2 lines,

```
JOIN TIME ON sched.clocked_in_time_utc BETWEEN time.interval_start_time AND time.interval_end_time

jOIN TIME ON sched.clocked_out_time_utc BETWEEN time.interval_start_time AND time.interval_end_time
```

iIt gives me an error as I dont think that is correct. 
How can I correctly pull in the min and max clock in and clock out time for the correct interval? Meaning I only want the earliest clocked in time and the latest clocked out time in that per half hour interval start and end time.

I appreciate anybody looking ! Thanks

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the sample data is in the first line shown as the row with Driver ID of 232? @jarlh

Comment: I added the output of what my current query gives me with the incorrect earliest clocked in time and incorrect latest clocked out time in that interval @jarlh

Comment: 1 row isn't really sample data ,same goes for desired result, can you mix in bit more data?

Comment: sorry - what would be more sufficent? more rows for sample data instead of just one?